# About the behavior of the negation operator with regard to bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operators, byte

Why does the `-` operator behave like it does when dealing with bytes?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"
#define BYTETOBINARY(byte)  \
  (byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
  (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0) 

int main()
{
char a =1;
printf (BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(a)); //00000001 
printf("\n");
printf("%d\n", a); //1    
a= ~a;
printf (BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(a)); //11111110   
printf("\n");
printf("%d\n", a); //-2    
a=-a;
printf (BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(a));//00000010  
printf("\n");
printf("%d\n", a);//2
}
```

Why is it `00000010`? Is it 2's complement? But how and why?

Comment: Yeah the negation operator `-`.

Comment: "Why does the - operator ..." Because that's what the standard defines! You should read about integer representation - specifically 2s complement, although not enforced by the standard.

Comment: But what is calculation it does in this case? @Olaf

Comment: `00000001` (one's complement)--> `11111110` (two's complement)--> `00000010`. The signed binary value `11111110` is decimal `-2`, so negating that will be `2`

Comment: Note: `char` can be signed or unsigned. When using it as small integer and with arithmetic operators, you **always** should explicitly use `signed char` or `unsigned` char!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unary `-` operator switches between positive and negative values in signed integer types.  On most machines, this is implemented with 2's complement.

2's complement is done by first flipping all bits, then adding 1.  So taking `11111110`, flipping the bits yields `00000001`, and adding 1 yields `00000010`.

This differs from the unary `~` operator, which is the bitwise-NOT operator, which simply flips all bits.